# case-insensitive regex for colon in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a string that has the form:

```
abcd:vxyz
```

That is: 4 chars followed by a colon then followed by three (or maximum) 4 chars.

I want to do case INSENSITIVE matches.

Can anyone help with the pattern?

Comment: If this is easy (and it is) what did you try before posting a question for all posterity on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Phrogz: Because I don't think its an effective use of my time (being predominantly a C++ programmer) to spend an hour or so on figuring out the expression - whilst it will take a Javascript expert less than a minute to figure it out (the first answers were posted under a minute). I don't have an ego, and I know what my strengths and weaknesses are. I don't mind asking for help from experts if the subject matter is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^[a-z]{4}:[a-z]{3,4}$/i
```

........

Comment: Does [a-z] handle all case sensitivity? (I thought it would be [a-zA-Z])?  TIA.

Comment: The i at the end does it, it's the case insensitive modifier http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: Ah, looks like this is the more compact version. I did not fully grok it when I first saw the expression - your explanation has made it clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following regex should work:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{4}:[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$"
```

The {4} part indicates that it should match exactly four copies of the previous symbol, which can be any character between 'a' and 'z', as well as 'A' and 'Z', inclusive.

The {3,4} part creates a range of copies between 3 and 4 inclusive, while the '^' symbol indicates that it should start at the beginning of the given string and the '$' sign indicates that it should end at the end of the given string.

Comment: You have showed this as a string, and not included the case-insenstive match.

Answer (score 2):

Your example was alphabetical, but it was unclear if your desired regex should be limited to that.  If you wanted to match *any* characters in those groups:

```
/^.{4}:.{3,4}$/i
```

Comment: He did in fact say "4 chars", not "4 letters" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another non-regex way to do this would be to `split()` on the colon. Check for length 4 on the first element, and length 3 or 4 on the second element.

```
var foo = 'abcd:123a';
var bar = 'fds:0';

var af = foo.split(':');
var isMatch = ((af[0].length==4) && (af[1].length==3 || af[1].length==4));
alert (isMatch);

var ab = bar.split(':');
alert ((ab[0].length==4) && (ab[1].length==3 || ab[1].length==4));
```